# Update PrimeFaces selectCheckboxMenu via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I want to update a PrimeFaces selectCheckboxMenu via Javascript with the selection stored on client side.

```
<h:form id="filter">
      <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="inputType" label="#{msg.labrel}" widgetVar="inputType">
        <f:selectItems value="#{filterAction.types}" var="type" itemValue="#{type.toString()}" itemLabel="#{type.displayName}"  />
      </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</h:form>
```

I already tried it via `PF('inputType')` and `$('#filter-inputType').find('input[type=checkbox]').checked=true`, but without success any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The widget var has "check" and "uncheck" methods. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.selectcheckboxmenu.js#L670

Comment: @Melloware: I always wondered why things like this are not in the documentation...

Comment: I know its a shame too because Rapster had a prototype of a document generator that scanned the widget for JSDoc, the TagLib for properties and generated the component page. But PrimeTek chose to go another direction with the new documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Melloware. Solution for selectCheckboxMenu control by JavaScript:

```
menu = PF('inputType');
index = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < menu.labels.length; i++) {
  if (menu.labels[i].textContent == 'label') {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}

menu.check($(menu.checkboxes[index]),true);
menu.uncheck($(menu.checkboxes[index]),true)
```